# Specific Commandbar does not close in contextmenu

Tags: excel, vba

I have write a script which display specific scripts in the context menu.
After programming, the contextmenu displays the scripts I want to launch, and the scripts runs well.

```
'SCRIPT POUR MENU CONTEXTUEL
Sub AddToCellMenu()
    Dim ContextMenu As CommandBar
    Dim MySubMenu As CommandBarControl

    ' Delete the controls first to avoid duplicates.
    Call DeleteFromCellMenu

    ' Set ContextMenu to the Cell context menu.
    Set ContextMenu = Application.CommandBars("Cell")

    ' Add one custom button to the Cell context menu "BL OK".
    With ContextMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, before:=20)
        .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "Bouton_BonLivraisonOK"
        .FaceId = 71
        .Caption = "Bon Livraison OK"
        .Tag = "My_Cell_Control_Tag"
    End With

    ' Add one custom button to the Cell context menu "LIVRAISON OK".
    With ContextMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, before:=21)
        .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "Bouton_LivraisonOK"
        .FaceId = 72
        .Caption = "Expédition OK"
        .Tag = "My_Cell_Control_Tag"
    End With

    ' Add one custom button to the Cell context menu "Livraison avec RELIQUAT".
    With ContextMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, before:=22)
        .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "Bouton_LivraisonReliquat"
        .FaceId = 73
        .Caption = "Expédition avec RELIQUAT"
        .Tag = "My_Cell_Control_Tag"
    End With

    ' Add one custom button to the Cell context menu "RAZ".
    With ContextMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, before:=23)
        .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "Bouton_CellBlank"
        .FaceId = 70
        .Caption = "RAZ"
        .Tag = "My_Cell_Control_Tag"
    End With

    ' Add a separator to the Cell context menu.
    ContextMenu.Controls(20).BeginGroup = True

End Sub
```

The problem is the contextmenu is still running in other excel files after closing the file.
I need your help for closing the function in contextmenu when I work on other Excel file.

```
Sub DeleteFromCellMenu()
    Dim ContextMenu As CommandBar
    Dim ctrl As CommandBarControl

    ' Set ContextMenu to the Cell context menu.
    Set ContextMenu = Application.CommandBars("Cell")

    ' Delete the custom controls with the Tag : My_Cell_Control_Tag.
    For Each ctrl In ContextMenu.Controls
        If ctrl.Tag = "My_Cell_Control_Tag" Then
            ctrl.Delete
        End If
    Next ctrl

    ' Delete the custom built-in Save button.
    On Error Resume Next
    ContextMenu.FindControl(ID:=3).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
I have to declare the opening/closing of CellMenu in the workbook.
Please refer to the following code:

```
 Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    Call AddToCellMenu
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    Call DeleteFromCellMenu
End Subenter code here
```